# How do I switch implementation at instantiation time?

Tags: ruby

I have a class in Ruby that holds some stuff, I'll call `FooBox`:

```
class FooBox
  ...
end
```

I have two possible backing-data stores for `FooBox` called `BoxA` and `BoxB` with different characteristics but the same interface:

```
class BoxA
  include Enumerable
  def put_stuff(thing)
    ...
  end
end


class BoxB
  include Enumerable
  def put_stuff(thing)
    ...
  end
end
```

How can I instantiate a `FooBox`, and, based on a parameter, decide whether to back it with a `BoxA` or `BoxB` implementation? I do not want to pass in the implementation into the constructor; I only want to pass something to determine which kind to use.

```
class FooBox
  def initialize(implementation_choice)
    # ???
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on how `FooBox` might make use of any of these implementations?  And why should it matter if you passed an actual implementation instance or an abitrary flag, what are you trying to avoid?

Comment: so you want to implement a Factory Design Pattern in Ruby?

Comment: A consumer of FooBox doesn't know about backing implementations, just how it wants it's data to be dealt with (in the abstract sense). FooBox looks at the parameter and goes "I see what you've requested here. Let me dig up my implementation for that."

Comment: @donnior A factory would imply that FooBox is emitting the implementation. It is not. It is the strategy pattern, if anything.

Comment: @donnior Doesn’t seem like that as the intention is not to create an object of unknown class *that the consumer of the library will use*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do something like this:

```
class BoxA
  def self.match? options
    # figure out if BoxA can be used given options
  end
end

# Implement BoxB (and other strategies) similarly to BoxA

class FooBox
  STRATEGIES = [BoxA, BoxB]

  def initialize options
    @options = options
  end

  def strategy
    @strategy ||= STRATEGIES.detect { |strategy| strategy.match? @options }
  end
end
```

This keeps the responsibility of “knowing” if the strategy is able to be used within the strategy itself (rather than making the context class monolithic), and then just picks the first one in the list that says it can work.

I’ve used this pattern (and similar variations for slightly different problems) several times and have found it very clean.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is create a mapping for the strategy's type and strategy class, just like @Andrew Marshall's solution

But to be better I would considering two things:

- The strategies' holder (here is the `FooxBox` ) now need to know every box implenentation, and hard-coding their names to itself; this is not a flexiable 
  approach, considering one day you want to add another strategy, go to the code and add it?  With ruby we can do it with a 'self registering' easily.
- You don't want to strategies holder will return implementation wildly, I mean both 'BoxA' and 'BoxB' or someday's 'BoxXYZ' should belong to same strategy
  concept, in Java, it maybe means all of them should implemente an `interface`, with ruby we generally do it with `include SomeMoudle`

In my application I use the following solution(just demo)

```
module Strategies
  def self.strategies
    @@strategies ||= {}
  end

  def self.strategy_for(strategy_name)
    @@strategies[strategy_name]
  end
end

module Strategy
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      def self.strategy_as(strategy_name)
        Strategies.strategies[strategy_name] = self
      end
    end
  end 
end


class BoxA
  include Strategy

  strategy_as :box_a

  def do_stuff
    puts "do stuff in BoxA"
  end
end 

class BoxB
  include Strategy

  strategy_as :box_b

  def do_stuff
    p "do stuff in BoxB"
  end
end

## test 
Strategies.strategy_for(:box_a).new.do_stuff
Strategies.strategy_for(:box_b).new.do_stuff
```

If you want to detect strategy with match block, you can change `strategy_as` to accept a block. then use `Strategies.strategy_for{...}.new.do_stuff`

Comment: Right, though I’d much prefer something like `Strategies.add_strategy BoxA` than reaching into `Strategies`’s internal data structure. Ruby doesn’t have interfaces, and `include` isn’t a substitute for them. You can also just define `strategy_as` in `Strategy` normally (instead of in a hook), and `extend Strategy` instead.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall thanks, It's my mistake, I just want to say 'include SomeMoudle', though it's not a substitute for interface, but it's more powerful than it. And personally I like including module, ^_^